# perfect distro for an old mac desktop (ppc g3) (320mb ram)

Tags: distribution-choice, macintosh, powerpc

I have on old mac desktop:

- Power PC G3 (300MHz)
- 320 MB Ram

I want to use it for browsing the internet and playing videos. What distro should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You might check out [Crux](http://cruxppc.org/), it seems to be the most promising entry in lightweight distros that support ppc catagory.

I also ran across [Slackintosh](http://workaround.ch/), although their promotional material isn't very exciting. You can find lots more [distros that support ppc](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=ppc) here. Several distros listed (including Ubuntu and my personal favorite: PLD-Linux) have actually dropped PPC support over the last couple years, so that that list with a huge grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say go with [Debian](http://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/). It supports many architectures including ppc.

Debian's quite user friendly and because it has a large user base, you'll probably get any questions you have answered quickly.

Debian has a comprehensive [installation manual](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/powerpc/).

EDIT: I just came across [this site](http://penguinppc.org/mac/) which seems to have quite a bit of info for ppc GNU/Linux users.